# Prove that $f(x) =0$ for at least one positive $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> **Problem**
>   Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ , such that first and last coefficients have opposite signs. Prove that $f(x) =0$ for at least one positive $x$.

I have an Inkling that i have to apply Bolzano's theorem .

Any hint or suggestion ?

Comment: Take the coefficient of the highest power to be 1 without loss of generality. Then $f(0) <0$ and $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to\infty$. Hence there is some $x>0$ such that $f(x) >0$. The intermediate value theorem shows that there is a root in $(0,x)$.

Comment: Please check whether i have understood it right or not.

Comment: Let Co<0 and Cn> 0 . f(0)>0 and f(x) > 0 for some x. Therefore f(c) =0 for some c between 0 and x.

Comment: I don't know you understood it, but copper's explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots +a_n x^n$, compute $f(0)$ and $f(x_0)$ for $x_0>n\max_k\left|\frac{a_k}{a_n}\right|$

Answer (score 0):

Use Descartes' rule of sign and fundamental theorem of algebra. The existence of such $x$ will be guaranteed. Link: https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/polynomial-functions/descartes-rule-of-sign